# Quicktime to Flash using PHP ? And chapters

Tags: php, flash, quicktime

For a client, i need to write a complex application used to stream tv episodes in flash format, at least, the player will be in flash.

It's a first for me, and i've a lot of question, since i don't really know about streaming.

But well, first, here is the constraints :

- Mac server (might be migrated to linux)
- PHP5
- Flash
- external library could be used with PHP

What i need to do at first, is to write some app (php, python, shell), or find one to convert over 500 quicktime videos to be able to be read within a flash player.

Then, i'll a back office, to add videos with meta data (the meta data will be simple html inputs), and, here is an important part of the project, the ability to generate chapters for each video (manually), the client will choose the start of a chapter, give it a name.

My questions :

- Is there any flash player able to do that ? or will i have to use 'playlist' such as youtube to simulate chapters ?
- Will it be easy to use the quicktime video within a flash player ?
- What would be your advices for such application ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're probably going to want to install and run [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to convert quicktime movs to flv or f4v. You may be able to add cue points (chapters) by using something like [FLVtool](http://www.ioncannon.net/web-design/109/metadata-cuepoint-flash-video-flvtool/).